# Como calcular distância da localização do usuário com outro endereço?

Tags: java, android, gps, geolocalização

O que preciso fazer é bem simples, mas não sei como faço.

Funciona assim: Passo um endereço para o usuário e assim que ele estiver no local ele pressiona um botão, ao fazer isso o aplicativo deve saber se ele está no local (ou bem próximo), caso esteja, executa um comando, caso contrário  informa ao usuário que ele está distante do local. Como posso fazer isso?

Estou usando Android Studio.

Comment: Você quer apenas saber como calcular a distância entre duas coordenadas ou quer saber como se faz tudo o que fala lá na pergunta?

Comment: E o que fez até agora? Está usando alguma API ou está usando o GPS nativo? Poderia dar detalhes?

Comment: Então, ramaral, preciso saber se a distância entre as duas coordenadas é próxima, pra validar se o usuário está no local. É tipo assim: evento XYZ na Rua Sem Nome, n° 10, quero pegar a coordenada do usuário e saber se ele está no local. Guilherme, ate o momento só tenho a interface (montada através dos dados do MySQL) só falta implementar essa função no botão existente, mas como sou novo em desenvolvimento mobile, não faço ideia de como começar hahaha fiz toda a aplicação usando tutoriais.

Comment: Bom, consegui obter a longitude e latitude do usuário (-22.75678733; -42.88711433) através desse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567171/how-to-get-users-gps-coordinates-by-clicking-a-button    e agora como faço para saber a distância entre essa coordenada e uma outra qualquer? Ao invés de longitude e latitude como no link acima, tem como capturar um endereço (nome de rua e número )?

Comment: Você não precisa ficar editando os posts e marcando-os como resolvido. Basta aceitar a resposta. Por favor, leia a página "TOUR" do site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a lib do próprio Google para isso.
[Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/)

Adicione no seu Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:x.y.z'
}
```

exemplo:

```
LatLng posicaoInicial = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
LatLng posicaiFinal = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(posicaoInicial, posicaiFinal);
    Log.i("LOG","A Distancia é = "+formatNumber(distance));

private String formatNumber(double distance) {
        String unit = "m";
        if (distance  1000) {
            distance /= 1000;
            unit = "km";
        }

        return String.format("%4.3f%s", distance, unit);
    }
```

`

Comment: Failed to find com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:x.y.z já troquei x.y.z por 0.3+, 0.3.1, 0.4+ mas não vai.. O que está faltando? Penso eu que seja uma library faltando, mas no sdk manager não achei nada que pudesse baixar

Comment: x.y.z isso significa que você tem pegar a ultima atualização da lib, ou seja: compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+

Comment: Valeu, cara, funcionou!  \o/

Answer (score 3):

Caso pretenda saber a distância do trajeto, você pode utilizar a [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=pt-br).

Essa API retorna por exemplo o tempo e a duração entre os pontos.

Exemplo: **Distância entre SP - RJ**

Utilizando as suas coordenadas.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=-23.562984,-46.654261&destinations=-22.951669,-43.210466&key=KEY_CODE
```

Retorno:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Christ the Redeemer Statue Rio, Rio de Janeiro - RJ, Brasil" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "Alameda Rio Claro, 313 - Bela Vista, São Paulo - SP, 01332-010, Brasil"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "449 km",
                  "value" : 449025
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "5 horas 45 minutos",
                  "value" : 20689
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Resultado: 5h 45min - 449 km